# Ensuring consistent colours for barplots in seaborn

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I've been working on a dataset using Jupyter Notebook, I am comparing quantities of items being moved through a warehouse vs the count of picks for those items.

I'm using Seaborn to render my plots.

I've got two barplots in a grid, and with the data unsorted the plots look like this:

[image: Unsorted data]

Using the following code:

```
plt.figure(1, figsize=(20,15))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

plt.subplot(gs[0,0], title="Count of SKU pick events")
sns.barplot(x='qty', y='sku', data=sku_count, palette='Spectral')
plt.subplot(gs[0,1], title="Sum of SKU quantities picked")
sns.barplot(x='qty', y='sku',data=sku_sum, palette='Spectral')
```

As can be seen, the colours of each bar correspond between the two plots.

The problem arises once I sort the data for each plot by their respective amounts (COUNT vs SUM):

```
sku_sum = sku_sum.sort_values('qty',ascending=False)
sku_count = sku_count.sort_values('qty',ascending=False)
```

And re-render the graphs using similar code:

```
plt.figure(2, figsize=(20,15))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

plt.subplot(gs[0,0], title="Count of SKU pick events")
sns.barplot(x='qty', y='sku', data=sku_count, palette='Spectral', hue_order=h_o)
plt.subplot(gs[0,1], title="Sum of SKU quantities picked")
sns.barplot(x='qty', y='sku',data=sku_sum, palette='Spectral', hue_order=h_o)
```

[image: Sorted data]

From the 4th row downwards the series colours do not correspond.

I thought to define my hue sequence in list, which I later reference using `hue` or `hue_order`:

```
#hue_order handling (TODO: NOT WORKING YET!)
h_o = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
```

I have tried using `hue` but I think that that is used for adding other dimensions to data, and with this code:

```
plt.figure(3, figsize=(20,15))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

plt.subplot(gs[0,0], title="Count of SKU pick events")
sns.barplot(x='qty', y='sku', data=sku_count, palette='Spectral', hue=h_o)
plt.subplot(gs[0,1], title="Sum of SKU quantities picked")
sns.barplot(x='qty', y='sku',data=sku_sum, palette='Spectral', hue=h_o)
```

Produces this result:
[image: Oh no the hues!]

Which is definitely not what I need.

Any suggestions on how to go about locking the hues across different graphs for the same set of series with different data?

Comment: Hi shouldn't be just hue="sku"? (can not test it now so just adding comment)

Comment: Happy to test for you! One sec...

Comment: @HubertDudek I tested this earlier and ran it again now...unfortunately produces the same result as the last figure in the question, while _technically_ producing the correct answer...

Comment: Any solution to this? Missing the same consistency. I think in your case a solution might have been to add the groups F and H but with value zero.